# UWP Filter Bluetooth devices for pairing

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp

I'm using code based on https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/cs/Scenario8_PairDevice.xaml.cs#L75 to scan for bluetooth devices to pair with in a UWP app.

I need to restrict the list of devices to audio devices only. Thus far, the only clue I've found is to request the System.Devices.Aep.Category of the device. For the external speaker I'm playing with, I get ["Communication.Headset.Bluetooth"]. Currently planning on just displaying the DeviceInformation object with 'headset' or 'speaker' in the categories.

Is there a list of all categories that are possible or a better solution?

Comment: Official doc does not contain this kind of list. Do you mean you've already used the AQS to create your own filter string? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/build-a-device-selector By the way, I found that the deviceInfo.GetGlyphThumbnailAsync seems returns the right thing when detecting.

Comment: I'm using the paired and unpaired bluetooth selector from the sample: `Selector = "System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}\""`
What would I add to that to restrict to AudioRender devices?

Comment: The ID e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-2‌​63b43f0f974 is just the Microsoft-defined class globally unique identifier for BlueTooth. To be honest I'm also not so familar with audio devices. But obviously  'headset' or 'speaker' is not enough for all cateories. Maybe you can check from ServiceClassID https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/aep-service-class-ids By the way, can I ask the reason about why you want to filter this? If I'm a user it seems I will not have so many ble devices.

Comment: The primary reason for the filtering is to avoid support calls for untested peripherals. This is a handheld IOT Core device and we're trying to be very focused on the specific needs of the user.

Comment: My service class id is 00f40965-e89d-4487-9890-87c3abb211f4. I'm not sure, but that seems also to be a very generic value.